# Symfony2/Twig: how to tell the custom twig tag to NOT escape the output

Tags: templates, symfony, twig

I created a custom tag which should work like that:

```
{{ thumbnail(image.fullPath,620) }}
```

unfortunately I have to use it like that

```
{{ thumbnail(image.fullPath,620)|raw }}
```

Is there a way to unescape directly in the twig extension?

My extension registers the thumbnail code like this:

```
 public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            'thumbnail' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'thumbnail'),
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The third argument of `Twig_Function_Method::__construct()` is an array of options for the function. One of these options is [`is_safe`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#automatic-escaping) which specifies whether function outputs "safe" HTML/JavaScript code:

```
public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        'thumbnail' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'thumbnail', array(
            'is_safe' => array('html')
        ))
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Is this specified in the documentation? I couldn't find it, but perhaps I didn't look hard enough.

Comment: @StephenOrr see the link in Crozin's answer.

Comment: thank you, it helped me $) can you add link to manual for this? want to know what more then 'html' options can be

Answer (score 10):

[Crozin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9634250/494560) is correct but because `\Twig_Function_Method` is now deprecated you can use `\Twig_SimpleFunction` as such:

```
return [
    new \Twig_SimpleFunction('thumbnail', [$this, 'thumbnail'], [
        'is_safe' => ['html']
    ]),
];
```

Answer (score 3):

Twig does it like this:

```
class Twig_Extension_Escaper extends Twig_Extension
{
...
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new Twig_SimpleFilter('raw', 'twig_raw_filter', array('is_safe' => array('all'))),
        );
    }
...
}
...

function twig_raw_filter($string)
{
    return $string;
}
```